# Twitter Streaming API Updating Favorite and Retweet Counts

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am currently collecting tweets by certain keywords with the twitter streaming api and noticing that the favorite and retweet counts are mostly 0 even from users with high followings since the tweets are being captured in near real-time. I want these stats to be updated if the tweet gains traction. For example, if a tweet received 10,000 favorites 6 hours after I captured it I want to receive an event(or even the same tweet again with the new favorite counts) and update the stats. Is there a way to do this?

I looked at the following two links below and found that you can follow a certain user id and so when someone favorites a user's tweet you will receive an update event. This obviously doesn't scale very well as I accumulate more tweets since I would receive many events for each user not even related to the specific tweet from that user that I want to follow.

https://dev.twitter.com/faq/finding-%26-counting-things

https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-users-followed-unfollowed-time-in-python/56774

Another possible work around I considered would be to have a separate search api thread that queries for the captured tweet id's several hours later for updated stats, but it won't scale again and it's hard to determine a good delay time interval.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Twitter Site Stream has been shut down and there's no way to answer the question now.